# Software for matching theorems to inputted conditions/hypotheses

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, mathematical-software

Many times I find myself going through analysis books, wikipedia and papers, looking for what is known for my functions/objects at hand.

So is there any software that at least tries to move in that direction i.e. putting any hypotheses and spit out list of possible conclusions.

For example, inputting univalent on unit disk, could output the top 10 results on them from a large database.

In fact, it should be fun programming it myself if it has not been done yet.

I understand that a big part of math research is coming across unexpected results while reading through papers for something else. But hey why not have additional help.

Comment: One possible program is "Search Google Books".  There may also be indexing schemes for formalized mathematical libraries.  Gerhard "First Go For The Obvious" Paseman, 2016.07.17.

Comment: There's also MathSciNet (Math Reviews online), though that's by subscription.

Comment: "In fact, it should be fun programming it myself if it has not been done yet."  Please do!  You will be much celebrated.